# Angular 6 Material - What classes are being used when using the components

Tags: html, css, angular-material, angular6

I was wondering, what classes are being used when an angular 6 material component is being used?

For example, if I wanted to further customize the Material Radio Buttons, I could use the edit the following CSS classes:

```
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle{
    border-color:rgb(66, 244, 81); 
}

.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle{
    color:rgb(244, 211, 66);
    background-color:rgb(244, 66, 66) ;
}

.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color:rgb(248, 37, 255);
}
```

Where can I find a list of the rest of the classes that are being used? I guess I could the dev tools from chrome to find out the classes, but is there a site that has the classes that are being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Material library is constantly growing and changing, so there's no good resource that lists everything in a way that would be any different than just inspecting dev tools.

As @Itay mentioned, you can just check the source for components. You can also go to the API page and inspect the source there.

Another resource is the generated `@angular/material/_theming.scss` theme file in your node_modules folder. This includes all the component themes, but is generated as part of the Material library build, so the full file isn't on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the material source code. Here's the [button_base](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/button) style for example.